# Binary quadratic form representing an integer with a vector of level N

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $N>1$ be an integer. Say I have a binary quadratic form
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b/2\\b/2 & Nc
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a,b,c$ integers which is not positive semidefinite. Then I know there is a vector $g=(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with coprime entries such that
$$
g^T M g < 0.
$$
Can we always find a vector $h = (s,Nt)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $\gcd(s,Nt)=1$ and $h^TMh<0$? If not, is there always a vector $h=(s,t)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $\gcd(s,t) = \gcd(s,N) = \gcd(t,N) = 1$?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are after.  Try any vector.  If it doesn't work, take the negative of that vector.  What am I missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo. I'm after $h^T M h<0$, not $h^T M g<0$.

Comment: If $h = (h_1, h_2)$ works, then let $g = gcd(h_1, h_2)$ and divide $h/g$ to satisfy your condition, yes?  I'm trying to understand where $s, N,$ and $t$ came from.

Comment: $s$ and $t$ are integers to be found. $N$ is a fixed positive integer, note that I've added it in the definition of the matrix (I don't think the conclusion is necessary otherwise)

Comment: Some naif questions that  might help (not sure): do you have any example of such a quadratic form? Have you considered it geometrically? Are you familiar with the spectral theorem? Have you worked out the case a = 1 = c, b = 0, N = -2?